# IFF statement in SQL Select Statement

Tags: sql

I am trying to write an IF statement which will perform the following.....

Here is an example of the results in the table....

```
Name        Exd Name                 RESULT
 HMAA  USA       USA                  HMAA USA
 HMIT  ITL       ITL                  HMIT ITL
 HMTT   LOG       HYT                HMTT LOG (HYT)
 LTYS   LTT      FYM                  LTYS LTT (FYM)
 TTTT   FFF      PPP                 TTTT FFF (PPP)
 FDSE   FGR      FGR                 FDSE FGR
```

The results should be displayed as follows

HMTT LOG (HYT) -----as the two names are different I wan to display the Exd NAme in brackets), however when
 HMAA USA , and the Exd Name is also USA - I only want to display the 'Name', not the Exd Name.

Is this possible in a IF statement....This is my script, as you can see it has the name + Exd Name, however above I would like to incorporate an IIF statement in here to only display as per the above logic.

```
SELECT  distinct  RNL.EmplID,
RNL.ServiceType, rnl.[name] + ' ' + '(' + rnl.[Exd Name] + ')' as 'Vessel'
FROM
resultsIB RNL (nolock)
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's SQL Server you can try:

```
select distinct RNL.EmplID, RNL.ServiceType, 
    rnl.[name] + 
    case 
        when rnl.[name] like '%' + rnl.[Exd Name]
        then ''
        else ' (' + rnl.[Exd Name] + ')'
    end as 'Vessel'
FROM resultsIB RNL (nolock)
```

or using [`iif` (SQL Server 2012 only AFAIK)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx) (*`IIF` is a shorthand way for writing a `CASE`*):

```
select distinct RNL.EmplID, RNL.ServiceType, 
    rnl.[name] + 
    iif(rnl.[name] like '%' + rnl.[Exd Name], '', ' (' + rnl.[Exd Name] + ')') as 'Vessel'
FROM resultsIB RNL (nolock)
```

Comment: `position`, `substring`, and `right` (or their SQL Server equivalents) would be other options if you didn't want to use LIKE. They'll all be doing the same suffix check of course.

Comment: @muistooshort the best way is to test them all and chose the most efficient one.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct  RNL.EmplID, RNL.ServiceType,
       CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(ExdName, Name) = 0
            THEN Name + ' (' + ExdName + ')'
            ELSE Name END AS 'Vessel'
FROM resultsIB RNL (nolock)
```